# How to show a list of comments on home page from all posts?

Tags: comments, comments-template

I have a custom post type for games on my site (https://pokerdiy.com). I have comments on these games and now want to show a list of recent comments on the home page of my site (kind of like the Facebook wall) to show the activity that is going on. I am using Elementor and want to be able to style it.

I tried to use the Posts Elementor block but this does not allow the selection of Comments.

Any suggestions appreciated....

Comment: Reach out to Elementor directly for support, or create a child theme that pulls comments in after Elementor's content. WP Core has a recent comments widget, so using the regular Editor you could do this easily with most themes.

Comment: I tried the Recent Comments widget and it did display the comments, however I had no way to template it - how would one normally go about styling it and rearranging the fields?

Comment: For styles, you could create a child theme or install a custom CSS plugin to write your own CSS. For actually moving things around, you'd want to write a plugin that outputs whatever HTML you want, and you could make that your own custom widget.

Comment: I tried reaching out to Elementor directly - no joy. Also tried the Facebook community page = no joy.